# Testing file IO errors in python

Tags: python, beginner, unit-testing, io, mocks

Below is a simple class with two methods: the first calls `open()` to read in a file. The second calls the first method and does error handling.

There is also a corresponding test class that tests the first methods returns data as expected and the other methods test the error handling of potential exceptions thrown by `open`.

Firstly, I would like to know if these tests are written in the appropriate manner using python3, mocking and patching as I am new to the language and especially to testing.

I also have a query to why mocking an exception to be thrown cannot be handled like the rest of the tests (see last test method)

**fileMethods.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def readconfig(myfile):
    try:
        filecontent = readfile(myfile)
        #   manipulation of filecontent
    except FileNotFoundError:
        filecontent = "FileNotFoundError"
    except PermissionError:
        filecontent = "PermissionError"
    return filecontent

def readfile(myfile):
    with open(myfile, 'r') as file:
        filecontent = file.read()
    file.close()
    return filecontent
```

**fileMethods_test.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock
import packageName.fileMethods

class TestIO(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_readfile_returns_string(self):
        mock_file_content = io.StringIO('Content in file')
        with mock.patch('packageName.fileMethods.open', return_value=mock_file_content, create=True):
            result = packageName.fileMethods.readfile('file_to_readin')
        self.assertEqual('Content in file', result)

    def test_readconfig_returns_content(self):
        with mock.patch('packageName.fileMethods.readfile', return_value="string", create=True):
            result = packageName.fileMethods.readconfig('file_to_readin')
        self.assertEqual('string', result)

    def test_readconfig_handles_FileNotFoundError(self):
        with mock.patch('packageName.fileMethods.readfile', side_effect=FileNotFoundError, create=True):
            result = packageName.fileMethods.readconfig('file_to_readin')
        self.assertEqual('FileNotFoundError', result)

    def test_readconfig_handles_PermissionError(self):
        with mock.patch('packageName.fileMethods.readfile', side_effect=PermissionError, create=True):
            result = packageName.fileMethods.readconfig('file_to_readin')
        self.assertEqual('PermissionError', result)

    # Does not work
    def test_readconfig_throws_OSError(self):
        with mock.patch('packageName.fileMethods.readfile', side_effect=OSError, create=True):
            self.assertRaises(OSError, packageName.fileMethods.readconfig('file_to_readin'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The design of the `readconfig()` function is seriously problematic.  It makes no sense to convert caught exceptions into data, as if the file literally contained the string `"FileNotFoundError"` or `"PermissionError"`.  If you don't have a good way to handle an exception, the right thing to do is let it propagate.

The `readfile()` function should be simpler:

```
def read_file(path):
    with open(path) as file:
        return file.read()
```

To note:

- Since "read file" is two words in English, it should not be written as a compound word.
- `myfile` could be better named.  It's a filesystem path, not a file handle.  Also, who is "me" in this case?
- The `'r'` mode is the default.
- You don't need to call `file.close()` on an already closed file.  The whole point of the `with` block is that the file is automatically closed when exiting the block.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback especially with my `read_file` method. I do not intent to return the error types of a string in an application. I was trying to understand how to test and account for exceptions thrown in a method/function which is used.

If like you say I let the error propagate like i did in the `read_file` method how would I test that an error has been thrown? I attempted to do this in the last test method `test_readconfig_throws_OSError` which does not work.

Comment: On Code Review, we take your posted code literally and seriously. Anyway, the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/129507/1157100) is not hard to find.